# Pagination in asp:DataGrid. Page numbers appearing below first column only?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, datagrid, pagination

I'm using an asp:DataGrid with Pagination. But I'm getting all the page numbers under the first column. See [this link for screen shot](https://amoghnatu.net/2013/11/13/question-help-required-pagination-in-aspdatagrid-aligning-page-numbers-to-the-center/).

I want the page numbers to span all the columns or at least not appear under the first column only. I tried searching a lot for relevant help but couldn't get it. Can someone please have a look at the link and help me out?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Gridview property, Expand the Pager Style and Set HorizontalAlignment="Center" .

Comment: I have already put the same. But still I'm getting the same result.

Comment: @AmoghNatu then i think it may be problem of css style sheet. That overrite the gridview style.